# Can anyone identify this species of spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

These spiders are all over everything on my padio in New Hampshire. Can anyone help me identify what they are? [image]

Comment: How big are they?

Comment: They look like acari: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acari

Comment: They are approximately 1mm in total size leg to leg. I am suspecting that they are some sort of mite, but they don't seem to bite, or be in the tick family (at least not human blood suckers).

Comment: Pretty clearly mites, not spiders, but unfortunately I'm not a mite guy.

Comment: It depends upon the environment or surrounding

Answer (score -1):

Based on your area and [this](https://www.orkin.com/other/mites/clover-mites) pest control site I believe that the bugs in your picture are not spiders, they are clover mites. I have found that some clover mites are a darker brown color and also slightly larger. This image gives a better view of the features of a clover mite, including the longer pair of front legs and oval shaped body: [image] Clover mites don't pose a threat to people or animals as they live off of either plants or fungi, but smashing them can leave stains on furniture and clothing.